# OOAD Design issue

Tags: java, oop, ooad

I have two tables: `tblCustomer`, `tblProduct`:

```
tblCustomer:
    Id: Integer, auto-increament
    Name: Varchar(30)
    ....

tblProduct
    Id: Integer, auto-increament
    Name: Varchar(50)
    customerId: Integer
    ....
```

And two classes: `Customer`, `Product`:

```
public class Product
{
    private int id;
    private int name;
    /* Other stuffs */
}

public class Customer 
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    /* get-set and others stuffs */

    public static boolean add(Customer cus) {
        /* This is for insert a customer to tblCustomer */
    }

    public boolean addProduct(Product pd) {
        /* This is for insert a product to tblProduct with current customer Id */
    }
}
```

When customer register account, it call:

```
Customer cus = new Customer(/* ... */);
Customer.add(cus);
```

and when customer buy a product:

```
Product pd = new Product(/* ... */);
currentCustomer.addProduct(pd);
```

But my teacher said it not correct in OOAD (and even OOP) because `Customer.addProduct` is operate on `tblProduct` table, is it right? What is good design for this case?

** Update: **
Product haven't a pre-defined yet, when a customer buy a product, the store will make it and delivery to customer, so two same products is rare happen, so is `tblCustomerProduct` need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a DAO tier that will contain the logical part of the methods `save`, `delete`, `update`, etc.

Here is how I usually do:

- `basepackage.domain`: contains all your entities (**data only, no logical part** - in your case  `Product` and `Customer`)
- `basepackage.dao`: contains all your DAOs, **only used to access the data**, basically one per entity, each one containing methods such as `findAll() : List<E>`, `findOne(K id) : E`, `save(E e) : void`, etc.
- `basepackage.service`: contains all your services, **the logical part of the app**. The services are the only ones that are calling the DAOs.
- `basepackage.presentation` (or `basepackage.web` for a webapp): contains the HMI/web services/... implementation.

Comment: Is service equal to control layer (in 3-tier model)?

Comment: It is equal to model (if you are refeering to MVC)

Comment: @BìnhNguyên Yes, it has several names: business tier, control tier, service tier, logic tier...

Comment: @JohnSnow Actually, the MVC takes part in the persentation tier of an n-tier architecture. Further info [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/175952/72730).

Answer (score 2):

What your teacher probably means is that you need a third table, named something like "CustomerProduct". This table contains the links between customers and which products they've bought.

```
tblCustomerProduct:
    Id: Integer, auto-increament
    CustomerId: Varchar(30)
    ProductId: Varchar(30)
```

so, when a customer buys a product, you add this data to the table CustomerProduct. This will remove redundant data and also make deletion alot easier

Comment: I haven't noticed that `Product` isn't pre-defined, when a customer buy a product, the store will make it and delivery to customer

Comment: Products should be stored in the system, how else would a customer buy a product without seeing which products that are avaliable? Your current solution will create a new row in the tblProducts each time a customer buys a product. THis will make these rows redundant. What your teacher wants you to do is create a third table as i've described.

Comment: Also note that your teacher said quote: `But my teacher said it not correct in OOAD (and even OOP) because Customer.addProduct is operate on tblProduct`. What your teacher means is that it is not correct to have Customer.addProduct operate on the table Product, in which you will need a third table that you "operate on".

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is right. It is not good Design because A class that you create should be cohesive. So that it should be responsible for doing the things that it can do. Here in your product class you have added customer id which is essentially a bad practice because A customer may purchase multiple products. This design will fail in that case. And also Product class doesn't need to know anything about the customer. All it has to know about is itself.

The relation between customer and product is an association which can be expressed as "customer buys product". So that customer id should not be there in product table.

Regarding the `currentCustomer.addProduct(pd);` method, it is not well suited because it is more suitable to product class rather than customer class.

The simple solution to your problem can be create a new class which can relate product and the customer.

For e.g.

```
CustomerProduct

customerid
productid
```

Inside this class you can add method like "AddProductForCustomer" and can write your database logic which will maintain the consistency.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: I haven't noticed that Product isn't pre-defined, when a customer buy a product, the store will make it and delivery to customer, so is a `CustomerProduct` needed?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên : How customer will buy product without seeing it ? It has to exist somewhere in the system. Then only he will buy it. Even though if you want to make it working then Insert product in the database first. Get the id of the inserted product and make an entry in the CustomerProduct table.

Answer (score 1):

In the table, the customer is assigned to a product, but in the method you give a customer and add a product.

So I would go for either a method pd.setCustomer(currentCustomer) instead of currentCustomer.addProduct(pd)

Or change the customer field in the product table to a products field in the customer table.